# Drupal Commons migrated site 500 error

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

So I had to migrate a drupal commons site from one server to the other on AWS. I exported the DB on one side and imported it again on the other using phpmyadmin and copied the installation folder from one server to the other. when I try to visit the site I get a php fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/
commons/profiles/commons/modules/contrib/file_entity/plugins/entity/file.inc'          
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/commons/
profiles/commons/modules/contrib/ctools/includes/plugins.inc on line 477
```

I don't understand the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [backup&migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module for easy migration.

1. Zip and copy all files to new server
2. Backup your database in file with backup&migrate module
3. Install old site on new server (run install.php and follow steps - you should probably change settings in /sites/default/setings.php file )
4. Go on /admin/modules and enable backup and migrate
5. Go on /admin/config/system/backup_migrate/restore upload your backup file and click restore button